# Have anyone used application/edn in request.ContentType for posting a Query request from C# .Net. Need escape sequence for quotes

Tags: c#

In my query, I need to post [{(:Users{:Users/uuid #uuid "40f69815-28fd-42df-a5ea-6ffff6cde27"})]";

as a application/edn Content type via HttpClinet.

As we have the escape sequence as /" for json, have anyone sent such requests using edn?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong slash in your example above. It should be `\"` to escape a quote. But regardless, you can just use JSON serialization to do all the escaping for you so you don't have to escape each character manually.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0